# Mine tokens stay on out

Tags: transactions, pending-transactions

Hello there i have a coupleof hunderd euro,s in WSM tokens i bought those with Metamask.
And i transferd them to Etherium but the some of mine tokens are out how do i get them in
I have contact Metamask they cant help me they told met to go to ethereum.
i searched on this site but i couldt find an answer
Sowhat muss i do to get mine token for swap or sell them or that i can use those tokens
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Hi! I'm having trouble understanding what happened here. Which chain were the tokens originally purchased on? How were the tokens transferred, and to where/whom? For reference, Metamask is not a blockchain, it's software that allows you to interact with different blockchains (a wallet, in other words). I'm not sure anyone here will be able to help, but we'd need to understand what happened more clearly to know.

Comment: Usually, you use an exchange like uniswap to convert your tokens into something like DAI or USDC. Be aware that some meme tokens are scams and will block any attempt to sell them.